# rails mysql2 database...where is it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

yeah, it's pretty stupid. maybe i'm searching for the wrong keywords. where the hell is the db file in the rails folder? I really need to edit stuff and I think it's ridiculous I'm trying to use console and getting a shitload of errors and having trouble deleting records, of all things.
(ie if it was sqlite3, it'd be in the db folder).

....*pulls hair out*

Answer (score 0):

Rails needs a separate mysql server running either on the same, or a different machine.  MySql isn't like sqlite, which uses a text file.  Check with your web host, they probably have a MySql database set up already.  Use something like Sequel Pro if you want to manipulate the data directly in the database outside of rails.

Comment: oh, i am running the server locally. I'm just not sure where the default location is? thanks

Comment: It's not like that, you don't refer to it as a file.  If it's running locally the host is simply "localhost"

Comment: oh, sorry, I'm new to database stuff.  how is the info stored then? o_o